# VS Code isn't identifying files in the same directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cmd, directory, runtime-error

[image]I was running a simple python program in VS Code which basically opens a file and prints out the contents in upper case. But the program is not able to identify the text file('mbox-short.txt') which is in the same directory.

The problem exists only when I run the program in VS Code terminal. The Code runs fine when I use windows command prompt.

I have attached the screenshot of the code executed on the terminal in VS Code and on CMD.
You can see the code running fine in CMD.[image]

The Code is given below!

```
fname = input("Enter the file name: ")
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
    for line in fhand:
        print(line.upper())
except:
    print("Invalid file name!")[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: The prompt shows you what folder you are in. That is where the file is looked for. You are one level too high

Comment: Yes, but isn't the VS Code supposed to do the same? since the file and the program are in the same directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current working directory in cmd is `D:\Python\files`, while it's `D:\Python` in VS Code. If you use the folder `files` as cwd, the result is exactly as the same as the one executed in external shell:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The problem is that VS Code isn't identifying the file in the directory when we hit the green run button, even though we are inside the same directory while clicking the run button. I hope the VS Code developers will look into this matter. : )

Comment: @MuhsinMuhammed. you may [file a report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues) in github to let developers know it.